# Protégé & Reasoning: Infer sameIndividualAs with enumerated classes

Tags: owl, semantic-web, protege, reasoning

So, here is something with OWL / Protégé I can't quite understand:
Let's say I have a class `Clazz` which is an enumerated class containing only the individuals `I1` and `I2`. I then create a third individual `I3` and declare it to be of type `Clazz`.
If I now start a reasoner, I would expect it to infer a `sameIndividualAs` between all (or at least some) of the indidivuals. This is not the case, I tested with both Hermit and Pellet reasoners.

If I explicitly state the three individuals to be different from each other, the ontology becomes inconsistent. Can anyone tell me why the individuals are not showing up to be `sameIndividualAs` in Protégé in the first case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there is no unique name assumption in OWL, the ontology is consistent until it is explicitly asserted that the manually typed individual is `owl:differentFrom` all of the individuals defining the class (the set restricted with `owl:oneOf`). If that's not asserted, in case there is more than one individual, the only inference that can be made is that, in your case, `I1`and `I2` are members of the class `Clazz`. `I3` should  be the same as one of the individuals, but there is no information to decide as which. You can remove this ambiguity by making `Clazz` defined as `owl:oneOf :I1`. Then there will be no ambiguity and sufficient information to infer that `:I3 owl:sameAs :I1`.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. I just tested with only one individual in `Clazz` and `sameAs`-relations are inferred. Thanks for that comprehensive explanation!